# Discord Invoke command for discord bot

Tags: discord, discord.py

I've created a bot, which now in my discord server, using the below code.

My question is, once I'm in the discord chat with the bot, how do I invoke the command to have the bot run the code, to gather the csv for the user list?  I'm not sure how to invoke the bot once it is in the chat/server to get the list.

```
"""A bot to list all members of a server."""
import csv
import time

from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

# constants
PREFIX = "~"
TOKEN = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx"

bot = Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')


@bot.event
async def on_command_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        return
    else:
        print(error)


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def stat(ctx):
    """Returns a CSV file of all users on the server."""
    await bot.request_offline_members(ctx.message.server)
    before = time.time()
    nicknames = [m.display_name for m in ctx.message.server.members]
    with open('temp.csv', mode='w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, dialect='excel')
        for v in nicknames:
            writer.writerow([v])
    after = time.time()
    await bot.send_file(ctx.message.author, 'temp.csv', filename='stats.csv',
                        content="Here you go! Check your PM's. Generated in {:.4}ms.".format((after - before)*1000))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean running your `stat` command? Since your prefix is `~`, you invoke the command by typing `~stat` in a channel.